# Max Number of Paths of Length 2 in a Graph with N Nodes

Tags: path, graph-theory

What is the maximum number of unique paths of length 2 in a graph with n nodes?

Comment: between 2 specific nodes? all paths with length 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a path of length 2 from u to v is u->u0->v (where u0 is a different vertex in the graph). in a [clique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_%28graph_theory%29) you can choose each of the n-2 (all but u,v) to be u0.

so you have n-2 paths between each two nodes - of length 2.

so overall, you can choose which are u and v : `choose(2,n) = n!/((n-2)!)` and for each of them you have n-2 possibilities, so total: `n!*(n-2)/((n-2)!)= n!/((n-3)!)=n*(n-1)*(n-2)`

Answer (score 3):

I think this is just the sum of degree choose two over all nodes with degree greater than one:

[image: formula]

Comment: I think this is correct. You focus on a given vertex b as a middle one: a->b->c. Now, the paths a->b->c and c->b->a count only once (these are the same paths). The number of vertices that are adjacent to b is d(b) (degree of b). Then to create a path of length 2 you choose 2 vertices from the set of all vertices adjacent to b. This gives the formula stated above.